# Не работает bower

Tags: frontend, сборка, bower

Когда выполняю запрос `bower search` то выдает следующее:

```
bower s jquery  
bower retry         Request to https://registry.bower.io/packages/search/jquery failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.8s
bower retry         Request to https://registry.bower.io/packages/search/jquery failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 4.0s
bower retry         Request to https://registry.bower.io/packages/search/jquery failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 4.2s
bower retry         Request to https://registry.bower.io/packages/search/jquery failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 10.3s
bower retry         Request to https://registry.bower.io/packages/search/jquery failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 26.6s
bower ETIMEDOUT     Request to https://registry.bower.io/packages/search/jquery failed: ETIMEDOUT
```

`node -v 6.11.3`, `npm -v 3.10.10`, `bower -v 1.8.2`, `macos high sierra`

При инсталляции пакетов такая же ситуация.

Comment: Загляните сюда, там есть советы по схожей проблеме: [Bower install - failed with ETIMEDOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22915961/5275890)

Comment: @DenisBubnov  может можешь подсказать где искать файл .bowerrc и что делать с proxy?

Comment: Думаю, что `.bowerrc` файл должен находиться в текущем рабочем каталоге, смотрите тут: [Bower can be configured using JSON in a .bowerrc file](https://bower.io/docs/config/). А также просто посмотрите тут, что и как устроено: [Bower manages](https://bower.io/). Обратите внимание на запись: *Bower requires node, npm and git.*

Comment: @DenisBubnov вот у меня почему не заходит на bower.io

Comment: @DenisBubnov через vpn заходит на сайт